# Using the json_normalize function when a key is missing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, json-normalize

I have come across an issue with the `json_normalize` function. When specifying a key which may be missing for an item, it throws a key error. As you can see, `listPeople` does not always exist in the file.

```py
df = {'Links':[{'id' : 1,'Gender' : 'X'},
         {'id' : 2,'Gender' : 'Y','listPeople' : [{'Person':'John', 'Age' : 42}] }
         ]
        }
```

```py
test = json_normalize(df, record_path= "listPeople", errors = "ignore")
print(test)
```

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html), using `errors = "ignore"` should do the trick, but this doesn't seem to be working?

Expected Output:

```
Person   Age
  NULL  NULL
  John    42
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`errors = "ignore"` works for missing dict keys, but you are missing a list that could contain multiple dicts, and that you want to pass as `record_path`. You could fill the missing `listPeople` with empty values:

```
[i.update({'listPeople':[{'Person':None,'Age':None}]}) for i in df['Links'] if 'listPeople' not in i.keys()]

test = pd.json_normalize(df['Links'], record_path=['listPeople'], meta=['id','Gender'], errors = "ignore")
```

Result:

|  | Person | Age | id | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | None | NaN | 1 | X |
| 1 | John | 42 | 2 | Y |